# Check type of string without conversion

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is it possible to check which one is numeric for example

abc or 123 without casting?

Obviously by our eye abc is not numeric. But I used Lodash's `_.isNumber(123)` it returned `false`, since I did not cast 123 of string to integer.

Comment: why you tagged JavaScript here?

Comment: @SagarV Since lodash written on javascript.

Comment: If he tag JavaScript and lodash, there are probability that he may get answer in both. He didn't clearly mentioned it in question

Comment: You can use Number.isFinite("123") to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if it is a valid number or not by using

Number(123) -> would give you a valid number
Number("abc")-> would return you NaN

The same can be achieved by unary operators
+123 -> would give you 123(as it is valid nymber)
+"abc"- > would be NaN (not a valid number)

check this snippet

```js
var number1=123
console.log(Number(number1))

var number2="abc"
console.log(Number(number2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `_.isNaN` from Lodash or simply `isNaN` of JavaScript.

```
_.isNaN(Number("123")) // false 
_.isNaN(Number("asds")) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd show you your options:

I don't see a reason to do this without casting. But yes, it is possible:

```
function isNumeric(str) {
    return /^\d+$/.test(str)
}
isNumeric('123') // true
isNumeric('abc') // false
```

This regex just checks if every single character in the string is a digit. So that's nice, but typically you'd try to avoid regex. So cast it, as the other answers have done:

```
function isNumeric(str) {
    return !isNaN(Number(str))
}
```

Or simply:

```
return !isNaN(+str)
```

Or, if you don't want to consider the empty string (`''`) numeric, just cast the cast to a boolean, rather than performing an `isNaN()` check:

```
return Boolean(+str)
```

Or simply:

```
return !!+str
```

The boolean cast is, as always in JavaScript, optional, depending on how you intend to use the result in the rest of your code. So really we can just do:

```
return +str
```

You can also use `parseInt()` if you want strings beginning with digits to be considered numeric.